# How to get custom logging working in CherryPy?

Tags: python, cherrypy

(Rewritten slightly following code modifications at my end plus answers given so far. Thanks to Andrew for the sample code which gave me the starting point for demonstrating that custom error logging works and then how I can break it!)

I'm trying to get custom logging working in CherryPy. I also would like to have log file rotation so I've followed the instructions in the documentation to replace the log handlers.

script_dir is set earlier on in my code to the directory where the script is running from.

```
cherrypy.config.update({'server.socket_host': '0.0.0.0',
                        'server.socket_port': 1234,
                        'tools.staticdir.on': True,
                        'tools.staticdir.dir': script_dir,
                        'log.access_file': "access1.log",
                        'log.error_file': "error1.log",
                        'log.screen': False,
                        'tools.sessions.on': True,
                       })

config = {'/':
             {
                  'tools.staticdir.on': True,
                  'tools.staticdir.dir': script_dir,
                  'log.access_file': "access2.log",
                  'log.error_file': "error2.log",
                  'log.screen': False,
                  'tools.sessions.on': True,
             }
         }

application = cherrypy.tree.mount(MyApp(), "/", config)

log = application.log

# Make a new RotatingFileHandler for the error log.
fname = getattr(log, "rot_error_file", "error.log")
h = handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler(fname, when='midnight')
h.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
h.setFormatter(_cplogging.logfmt)
log.error_file = ""
log.error_log.addHandler(h)

# Make a new RotatingFileHandler for the access log.
fname = getattr(log, "rot_access_file", "access.log")
h = handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler(fname, when='midnight')
h.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
h.setFormatter(_cplogging.logfmt)
log.access_file = ""
log.access_log.addHandler(h)
```

With the script running, logging happens as follows:

- Standard access logging goes to BOTH access1.log (defined at the global level) and access.log (defined at the app level)
- Error logging only goes to error1.log (defined at the global level)
- Nothing gets logged to *2.log (as expected)

So, it looks like CherryPy has a problem with error logging going to app-specific config. Generally that wouldn't worry me except that I do want to use the rotating log file handler but I don't know how to modify the logging sessions at the global level as I have done for the app-specific level.

Thanks.

Comment: It works ok for me. Do CherryPy's errors come through?

Comment: Yes, they do. I get stack traces when exceptions occur along with a more detailed list of the header values.

Comment: Updated my answer with tested example.

Comment: Funny thing is cherrypy seems to need to throw an error for it to log your error to the log file.  I will look into it some more.

Comment: So again, when exactly are you trying to log something? From your example I can see you have everything static. Also, did you try attaching your handler globally to cherrypy.log?

Comment: My understanding of what I've been seeing is that CherryPy won't log errors to an application-level error log. All testing I've done seems to show that it will only log errors to the global configured error log (if there is one). This is why I wasn't getting any error logs - I was only configured an application-level log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my question about how to set up the log handlers for the global log instead of the app-level log, here are the changes:

```
cherrypy.config.update({'server.socket_host': '0.0.0.0',
                        'server.socket_port': 1234,
                        'tools.staticdir.on': True,
                        'tools.staticdir.dir': script_dir,
                        'log.access_file': "access1.log",
                        'log.error_file': "error1.log",
                        'log.screen': True,
                        'tools.sessions.on': True,
                       })

config = {'/':
             {
             }
         }

application = cherrypy.tree.mount(HealthCheck(script_dir, service_fqdn, my_ip), "/", config)

logscope = cherrypy.log

# Make a new RotatingFileHandler for the error log.
fname = getattr(logscope, "rot_error_file", "error.log")
h = handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler(fname, when='midnight')
h.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
h.setFormatter(_cplogging.logfmt)
logscope.error_file = ""
logscope.error_log.addHandler(h)

# Make a new RotatingFileHandler for the access log.
fname = getattr(logscope, "rot_access_file", "access.log")
h = handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler(fname, when='midnight')
h.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
h.setFormatter(_cplogging.logfmt)
logscope.access_file = ""
logscope.access_log.addHandler(h)
```

or, in a nutshell:

- leave the application config empty. I'm only defining it so that CherryPy starts quietly.
- change the log scope from application.log to cherrypy.log

To be slightly more tidy, the references to access1.log and error1.log can change to access.log and error.log but I left them like that to confirm that I was overwriting the global settings.

Answer (score -1):

Use something like this...

```
import cherrypy
from cherrypy import log

class MyApp(object):
    def index(self):
        log.error(msg='This is My Error ', context='HTTP', severity=20, traceback=True)
        return "Hello World!"    
    index.exposed = True


cherrypy.tree.mount(MyApp(), "/")

cherrypy.config.update({'tools.staticdir.on': True,
    'tools.staticdir.dir': 'C:\\Documents and Settings\\d\\My Documents\\Aptana Studio 3 Workspace\\ScratchPad',
    'log.access_file' : "access.log",
    'log.error_file' : "error.log",
    'log.screen' : False,
    'tools.sessions.on': True,
    })


cherrypy.engine.start()
cherrypy.engine.block()
```

This will log the error.  I believe there's an issue loading the config in your code.  I also think static dirs needs to be turned.

Hope this helps and Happy Coding!

Comment: Essentially it's the same call as in the question

Comment: This worked for me.  The other problem he could have is that the user running his cherrypy app doesn't have permission to write to the error.log file.

Comment: Yep, hence my question

Comment: I don't think that it is a write permissions problem. Is "cherrypy.log.error" the same as "cherrypy.log"? I've just realised that maybe my call is trying to write to the access log but that has to follow a strict format?

Comment: Nope - switching to cherrypy.log.error doesn't make any difference :-(

Comment: Are you calling cherrypy.log() from a request handler? If not, the problem might be that you didn't define the logger globally.

Comment: jwalker - yes, it does look like it is a global vs app-specific issue but I don't know how to attach a custom log handler at the global level. I've revised my question to make that clarification.

Comment: Andrew - thanks for the sample. It helped me modify my code further to (a) get it working and then (b) break it by putting my modifications back in.